# How can I reformulate "A for B based on C" to make it not ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity

I have a title  "A for B based on C", but it is ambiguous, as either A or B could be based on C. In my case actually A is based on C. How can I reformulate the sentence to make it not ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you say "C-based A for B"?

or "Treating B using A based on C"?